Crawl data in Top 250 Movies IDMb
Please, i need someone help me. I can't understand why I only crawl 25 movies instead of 250. My code:
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250"
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

html_doc = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

ls = soup.find_all("div", class_="sc-b189961a-0 hBZnfJ cli-children")
print(len(ls))

The result is 25. Link: https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250, this has 250 movies and I using BeautifulSoup. The result len(ls) should be 250.
Please, explain and help me fix this. Thank you very much!
I hope I can crawl fully data on this Web

You need to extract the full list of movies from the JSON for Linking Data element. It's a JSON object from which the required information can be easily extracted.
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

script = soup.select_one("script[type='application/ld+json']")

data = json.loads(script.text)

movies = []

for movie in data["itemListElement"]:
    movies.append({k: movie["item"][k] for k in ["name", "url", "duration"]})

movies = pd.DataFrame(movies)

print(movies)

Sample output:
                                             name                                     url duration
0                        The Shawshank Redemption   https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/  PT2H22M
1                                   The Godfather   https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/  PT2H55M
2                                 The Dark Knight   https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/  PT2H32M
3                           The Godfather Part II   https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071562/  PT3H22M
4                                    12 Angry Men   https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050083/  PT1H36M
..                                            ...                                     ...      ...
245                         It Happened One Night   https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0025316/  PT1H45M
246                                       Aladdin   https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103639/  PT1H30M
247                                      Drishyam   https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4430212/  PT2H43M
248                            Dances with Wolves   https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099348/   PT3H1M
249  Gekijôban Kimetsu no yaiba: Mugen Ressha hen  https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11032374/  PT1H57M

[250 rows x 3 columns]


thank you, but i'm a beginner, so please tell me why it has line 'accept' : 'text/html', or give me some learning resources about that. I have tried Inspect this web and open 'Network' tabs but i still don't understand.

Sure. The 'accept': 'text/html' header tells the server that the client (the crawler) would prefer to receive the response in HTML. It's possible that the server might respond in a few different formats, like HTML, JSON or XML. You are expressing a preference for a specific format.
